# Regex - How to match a string until "either one of these characters” in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, alteryx

I have a dataset that contains a field with credit card merchant data. I want to use a regular expression to pre-process the values ("Clean Value" before using a fuzzy match to standardize the fields ("Desired output")

```
[merchant]         [clean value]    [desired output]
UPS1Z3734A345      UPS              UPS
UPS 1Z68A3125      UPS              UPS
HOME DEPOT #3421   HOME DEPOT       HOME DEPOT
STAPLES - #123     STAPLES          STAPLES
STPLS #4560        STPLS            STAPLES
```

There are a number of different cases I need to be able to tackle (e.g. "-", numeric values, "#" characters, etc.)

I am fairly new in regex, but this is what I have come up with so far

```
(.+)[?=#]
```

However, this only addresses when there is a "#" in the string. Furthermore, if there are no non-letter characters in the string, the field returns blank

I'd love to get some help on how to properly craft this expression.

Comment: What about `^([a-zA-Z\s]+)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this returns a lot of null values.

Comment: can you show example which returns null?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
((?:[^\d#-]){2,}).*$
```

it will create a group that should contain your clean value. (any char until it finds a digit, # or -)

https://regex101.com/r/tFUcct/1

Comment: This works really well! I have come across an exception. There are instances where I need to keep a digit, when it's found attached to a string of letters. For example, 14TH Street Coffee currently returns "TH Street Coffee", but I would like the "14th" to be parsed out fully. Is it possible to tackle an exception like this with Regex?

Comment: this `((?:^[\da-zA-Z]{3}[^\d#-]{0,})).*$` should allow up to 3 digits at the beginning of the match https://regex101.com/r/tFUcct/3